# Selenium Python Webdriver chrome print src's of all imgs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to print all src of imgs in the page, i want to see if it recognize it,
cuz when i do

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png'").click()
```

its says:

```
    C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe C:/Users/Bar/PycharmProjects/yad2/Webdriver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bar/PycharmProjects/yad2/Webdriver.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png'").click()
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Bar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png' because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png'' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

I have tried with `css_selector` , didn't work , so I want to print all of the srcs of the `imgs`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok propably @Saurabh Gaur were right there is Iframe in the site , 
Simple solution ,

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("FrameID"))
```

Thats it from there i could find the button , then i comeback

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

and from here i can continue to the next Frame Thats it!
@Saurabh Gaur Thank you So much! , you were Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png' because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png'' is not a valid XPath expression.

Actually your `xpath` is syntactically incorrect, you are missing to close square bracket `]`, So you should try as :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//img[@src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png']").click()
```

Or using `css_selector` as :-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[src='http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad.png']").click()
```

And if you want to print all `img` src attribute try as :-

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
for image in images :
  print(image.get_attribute("src"))
```

Comment: Ok, then its what i was afraid not to find, i can't find that button, its kinda when i click on something its like drop down which their i have my button, this dropdown so how can i find this button?
this is the XPath when i rightclick it then view code, and then i R-Click XPath - /html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/img
Or by Element-
<img style="border: 0px;" src="http://images.yad2.co.il/Pic/site_images/yad2/MyYad2/images/myorderbottom/new/jump_ad_disabled.png" alt=""> which i can't find in the list

Comment: There is a chance the site as blocked the option to find the elements? because i have printed all of the img sources and its find all but the one i want, the one i want propebly using request or something, can i do something?

Comment: You mean you are finding all the img src except one Right??

Comment: If I'm right, look at page source and verify this img, may be this img inside any frame or iframe.. if it is you need to switch that frame of iframe before find this img. Please verify it and let me know

Comment: This image is inside table and not frame , you can see by the XPath i have wrote, its inside of table. there any chance the site has protect this sepcific content? if yes do you think i can pass it?

Comment: Could you share your HTML for this img with two three lavel above and below??

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pWbYT4iz - search for Jump Ad or <!-- Jump Ad -->
this is the button i want to click on , sorry for the mess couldn't paste it normally

Comment: There is a chance that this button is sending post or get request?, can i involve requests with selenium?

Comment: I think you should click on `<a>` instead of `<img>` because clickable element is `<a>` here . You can find it with the img reference using `parent` axes. Something like using this xpath `//img/parent::a`

Comment: Hi found Iframe, can you explain me what is it? when i click the dropdown its makes a big table which the iframe is spreading all over it , this is the cause of the issue?

Comment: You need to switch that iframe before finding element by using their id or name as `driver.switch_to_frame("iframe name or id")`